# About .net core one-to-many association

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I am using .net core and I want to make association in database.

A customer can have more than one "treatment" record. How can I list it?
So I want to list the treatment records of a client. can you help with this?

**Model / Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BusinessCode { get; set; }
}
```

File "GetCustomerDto.cs" inside dtos folder

**Dtos/Customer/GetCustomerDto.cs**

```
public class GetCustomerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string BusinessCode { get; set; }
}
```

"Treatment.cs" file inside model folder

**Model / Treatment.cs**

```
public class Treatment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ToothNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ToothGroup { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}




     var dbCustomer = await _context.Customers.Where(c => c.UserId == UserId)
                                                     .Include(c => c.Treatments)
                                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't see UserId in your Customer  class

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class Customer
{

[Key]    
public int Id { get; set; }
.....

[InverseProperty(nameof(Treatment.Customer))]
 public virtual ICollection<Treatment> Treatments { get; set; }  
}
public class Treatment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))]
    [InverseProperty("Treatments")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    .........

}
```

and if you use net 5+  fix your query

```
var customers = await _context.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.Treatments.Where(c => c.UserId == UserId))
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
```